# Water tube coming out of (going in?) to HVAC has black in it. How bad is it? Do I need to call a professional NOW?

Tags: plumbing, hvac

Pardon my ignorance. There is a clear-ish tube connected to our HVAC and a water pipe. I think the water pipe is the drain pipe which means the HVAC sends water out of the tube out the drain. I assume.

Where the tube is connected to the drain end has some black-ness.

I'm just wondering how bad it is? As in do I need to get someone to come NOW or can I wait?

Pictures below. There are two tubes -- the right tube is our neighbors (don't ask).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: That gray box near the floor is a condensate pump.  Condensation from the ac coil trickles into it. When enough water gets in a float switch activates the pump which pushes water through the clear tube to the sewer. You can pour som bleach water into the gray boxes and force the pump to cycle a few times. Then pour a rinse water into it to purge the bleach out. Algae in that clear line could eventually block the flow and cause a overflow from the pump making a wet mess on the floor

Comment: So it is safe to pour bleach? Like a cup? 2 cups?

Comment: Mix bleach with water 50/50. And finish with a gallon of fresh water rinse

Comment: @Kris, you should put that in the answer box.

Comment: Agreed. Once you do I can mark it as answer. Thank you!